# What argument(s) are available for event type onInput?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

As I am trying to understand html / javascript / vue, I came across following code snippet.

```
        <input type="text" onInput="doAction(event);">

        <script>
            var mesdata = {
                message: 'type your message'
            };
            var app = new Vue ({
                el: '#app',
                data: mesdata
            })
            function doAction(content){
                mesdata.message = content.target.value;
            }
        </script>
```

I also saw following that achieved the same result

```
        <input type="text" onInput="doAction(this);">

        <script>
        ... same as above ...
            function doAction(content){
                mesdata.message = content.value;
            }
        </script>
```

As I played around with `content.type`, I figured out that I was passing in input type and text type.

I can understand the use of `this`, but would like to know where `event` came from. As I was searching through [w3 school definition of onInput event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp), I did not see any passable argument. What is the good reference to know about these definitions of each event arguments?

Also, what kind of preventative measure can I take to avoid type mismatch?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Other_event_concepts

Comment: I believe in that case it is specifically using the global `event` object, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event. However, if you are using Vue then you shouldn't be using the `onInput` attribute at all. With Vue you'd use `v-on:input` or `@input` instead.

Comment: Or more specifically, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handlers_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value

Comment: Quoted code is an obsolete way to do this, this is how this was done in Web 1.0. `event` and `this` are very special in this context. As for Vue, stick to `v-on` like it was suggested. Also, don't use w3schools as a reputable source, because it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the inline event handler `onInput="doAction(event);"` there are two variables that are known:

- `this`, the DOM element that triggered the event
- `event`, the global variable `window.event` that refers to the event just triggered

So when you call `doAction` with parameter `this` you get the value of the DOM element by applying `value`. When the parameter is `event` you need to first get the DOM element that triggered the event and then its value (`target.value`).

Here's a demo. Notice that inline event handlers are not recommended and event handlers should be used instead (see [MDN: Inline event handlers — don't use these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these)).
Notice also that since the event object is automatically passed to the event handler you don't need to specify it in `addEventListener` (see [MDN: Event objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_objects)

```js
// wrong variable naming, the parameter should be e, ev, evt, ...
function doAction1(content) {
  console.log(content.target.value);
  console.log("Is content an event?", content instanceof Event);
  console.log("Is content === window.event?", content === window.event);
  console.log('Is content.target === document.querySelector("input")?', content.target === document.querySelector("input"));
}

function doAction2(content) {
  console.log(content.value);
  console.log("Is content an event?", content instanceof Event);
  console.log("Is content an element?", content instanceof Element);
}

function doAction3(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  console.log("Is e an event?", e instanceof Event);
}


// use addEventListener rather that inline event handler
// event object is automatically passed to event handler
document.querySelector("#myInput3").addEventListener(
  "input",
  doAction3
)
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="parameter is event" onInput="doAction1(event);">

<input type="text" placeholder="parameter is this" onInput="doAction2(this);">

<input id="myInput3" type="text" placeholder="parameter is event">
```